# what is the difference between a slope field & a solution curve& a vector field?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

please tell me the difference. im lost. the above question suffices my issue. i dont get why we have these three things in my ODE class. i think the slope field is great and doesnt muddy the waters (as far as seeing the function geometrically).

Answer (score 1):

slope field = vector field and combination of all slope lines forms solution curve for specific problem.

Comment: so what is the difference between a direction field and a phase portrait? @metamode